# Specific remark to the definition of measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

> **Definition 1:** The triple $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is called *measure space*, if $\mathcal{M}$ is $\sigma$-algebra with identity $X$ and
>   $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive measure on $\mathcal{M}$.
>
> **Definition 2:** Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty\}\cup \{-\infty\}$ be a function. We
>   say that $f$ is a *measurable function* on $X$ if for any $c\in
>  \mathbb{R}$ the preimage $f^{-1}((c,+\infty])\in \mathcal{M}$.
>
> Then it is easy to prove that $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}),
>  f^{-1}(\{+\infty\}), f^{-1}(\{-\infty\})$ are measurable.

Hence we can assume that all our functions are finite, i.e. $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$.

Can anyone explain to me in rigorous way why we can assume that our we can restrict our attention to finite functions?

Would be thankful for your help!

**EDIT:**

**Theorem:** Suppose that $f$ is measurable on $X$ with $f(X)\subseteq G$ where $G$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\varphi:G\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $\varphi\circ f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable function.

Note that in the above theorem $f$ can takes on infinite values.

**Corollary:** Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty\}\cup \{-\infty\}$ be a measurable function on $X$. Then functions $f^2,af,f+a$ are measurable and if $f(x)\neq 0$ on $X$ then $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is measurable.

I do not see how to apply the above theorem to this corollary because $f$ takes on infinite values and the maximal open set $G$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $G=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What text is this from? (Certainly it's not true that in *all* circumstances we can WLOG restrict attention to $X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, so there's presumably some more context.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Unfortunately the book I am reading is the Russian book.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, please take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just my interpretation.

Let $E,E_{-\infty},E_{+\infty}$ be the measurable sets where $f$ is finite, $-\infty$, $+\infty$.

Let $\tilde{f} = f \cdot 1_E$. This is finite valued.

If $\phi$ is continuous, then $\phi \circ \tilde{f}$ is measurable.

If there are sensible values for $\phi(\pm \infty)$ we can define
$\tilde{\phi} = \phi \circ \tilde{f} \cdot 1_E + \phi(-\infty) 1_{E_{-\infty}} + \phi(\infty) 1_{E_{\infty}}$ which is measurable.

For $\phi(x)= x^2$ let $\phi(\pm \infty) = \infty$, for $\phi(x) = ax$ let $\phi(\infty) = (\operatorname{sgn} a ) \infty$ and for $\phi(x) = x+a$ let
$\phi(-\infty) = -\infty$, $\phi(\infty) = \infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I am reading it right now. What do you mean by sensible values for $\varphi(\pm \infty)$?

Comment: The function $\varphi:G\to \mathbb{R}$ and I guess that the $\varphi(\infty)$ does not make sense, right?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit sloppy, but it is not really inconsistent. I think in the last corollary the author means to pick appropriate values for $\phi(\pm \infty)$ where $\phi$ is one of $x \mapsto x^2, x \mapsto ax, x \mapsto x+a$.

Comment: I am a bit lost! The author claims that if we define arithmetic of extended real line for example $a+\infty=\infty$ and $0\times \infty=\infty$ or $\infty-\infty=0$ then in the above theorem we can take off the condition of finiteness. Is it clear?

Comment: It is only clear to me of there is an 'obvious' choice for $\phi(\pm \infty)$. For example, if $\phi = \sin$, I have no idea how I would define $\phi(\pm \infty)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer!